# Update set select where condition using functions T-SQL SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to process some modification on values of a table like following

```
DECLARE @tmpMap TABLE(Ptc int, Path int);

INSERT INTO @tmpMap(Ptc, Path) 
    SELECT ContactPointId_fk, PathId_fk 
    FROM t_PathContactPoint

UPDATE @tmpMap 
SET Path = (SELECT dbo.HKA_GetLeafIDFromPath(Path))
```

As you can see I am creating temporary table which allows me to process calculations with a scalar function that I created which returns int.

What I want to do is to specify that I need to update only rows where the result of the function is different from -1.

```
UPDATE @tmpMap 
SET Path = (SELECT dbo.HKA_GetLeafIDFromPath(Path) 
WHERE (the result of the function is different from -1))
```

Any ideas on how to do this with T-SQL in SQL Server please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `APPLY`:

```
UPDATE t
SET Path = g.LeafId 
FROM @tmpMap t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ( dbo.HKA_GetLeafIDFromPath(Path) ) ) g(LeafId)
WHERE g.LeafId <> -1;
```

Comment: i got the following error : Table-valued function 'HKA_GetLeafIDFromPath' cannot have a column alias.

Comment: Just Modify your answer and put CROSS APPLY (select dbo.HKA_GetLeafIDFromPath(Path)) as g(LeafId) i.e: add select before the function call and ill check it as valid answer. thank you for pointing CROSS APPLY which resolved my issue.

Comment: @KarouiHaythem . . . Duh.  It's not a table valued function, it is just a regular function.  I would more typically do this with `values()`.